# Changing iframe lengths by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm very new to javascript and this might be a dumb question.
Working on a school website, I need to shorten/lengthen an iframe while on a specific page.

So say I have a navbar on top, with an iframe underneath.
Would it then be possible to add an id to one of these links, attaching something like

```
function iframeLength(){
  frame.obj.length = 200;
}
```

I have tested this code out, it works like a charm. The thing is, I don't know if I can attach an id to a `<a href="">` , because I'll need something to base the iframe length on.

Thank you,
Michiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return iframeLength();">Do it!</a>
```

Comment: I think this looks a lot like what I need, very simple but i didnt think of it. Will check out tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery

Try somethink like this

```
<a id = myId href="">
```

In javascript

```
var aWidth = $('#myId').width();
frame.obj.length = aWidth;
```

Hope this help you ;)

Comment: I think the question is different. What Michiel really want is to execute his function when the link is clicked.